# Swagger Codegen for Groovy imports ArrayList incorrectly

Tags: gradle, groovy, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am using the swagger code generator v2.2.3 to generate the messaging layer for a groovy application.

Therefore I use the `org.hidetake.swagger.generator` gradle plugin to run the generator during the build.

The generation itself works, but the resulting import for the `ArrayList` type is wrong - it refers to the models package, not to the java type.

An example for the api spec for an erroneous model would be

```
TestModel:
  properties:
    someField:
      type: array
      items:
        type: integer
```

which results in

```
package com.enchant.messaging.model;

import groovy.transform.Canonical
import com.example.messaging.model.ArrayList;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import java.util.List;
@Canonical
class TestModel {

    List<Integer> someField = new ArrayList<Integer>()
}
```

The gradle task to generate the sources is

```
task generateApi {
    inputs.file("$projectDir/$swaggerSourceFile")
    doLast {
        def config = new CodegenConfigurator()
        config.setInputSpec("file:///$projectDir/$swaggerSourceFile")
        config.setOutputDir("$buildDir")
        config.setLang('groovy')
        config.setAdditionalProperties([
                'apiPackage'    : 'com.example.messaging.api',
                'modelPackage'  : 'com.example.messaging.model',
                'sourceFolder'  :  '../src/main/groovy'
        ])
        new DefaultGenerator().opts(config.toClientOptInput()).generate()
    }
}
```

Is this a bug in the groovy source code generator, or is the List class configurable for the swagger code generator?

Comment: Do you mean to say that while you are expecting `array`, `list` is generated?

Comment: Please open an issue via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new so that the swagger codegen community can help you out.

Comment: @Rao I am expecting, that `import java.util.ArrayList` is imported and not `com.example.messaging.model.Arraylist`, i.e. as this is Groovy, I expect nothing to be imported, as `ArrayList` is available by default in Groovy.

Comment: @WilliamCheng I''ll do that!